# Automatic Facebook post from Twitter list

Tags: facebook, twitter, automation

Is it possible to automatically post other peoples' posts on my Facebook? If so how do I do it?

I am trying to create a page which takes information from Twitter and posts it automatically.

Comment: Both webapp requests and development are off-topic, but I think phrasing it this way is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [If-This-Then-That](http://www.ifttt.com)? You can connect services such as Twitter and Facebook together and then add logic to complete and automate the process. As an example, every time I post a new blog article, IFTTT automatically tweets it.

Comment: That's the way I'd tackle it. Specifically with the "New tweet by a specific user" trigger on the [Twitter](https://www.ifttt.com/twitter) channel and the "Create a link post" action on the [Facebook](https://www.ifttt.com/facebook) channel. The downside is that you'd need a separate applet for each Twitter handle.